# InvocationException error from load method of hibernatetemplate

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting

> com.sun.jdi.InvocationException

while calling `hibernatetemplate.load` method

```
FrTicket fr=getHibernateTemplate().load(FrTicket.class, id);
```

[image: screenshot]

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:412)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.dao.ticket.TicketDAOImpl.getFrTicketById(TicketDAOImpl.java:1314)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getFrTicketById(Unknown Source)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.service.fr.FrTicketServiceImpl.getAllVicinityFrTicket(FrTicketServiceImpl.java:1202)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getAllVicinityFrTicket(Unknown Source)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.service.closeticket.MQClosureHelper.autoCloseTicket(MQClosureHelper.java:265)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.service.closeticket.MQClosureHelper.doAutoClose(MQClosureHelper.java:344)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.process.flow.ProcessFlow.closeFrTicketByNewFlow(ProcessFlow.java:1282)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.*handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:214)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at com.cupola.fwmp.auth.AppAuthFilterProxy.doFilter(AppAuthFilterProxy.java:27)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2062)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:906)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:318)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2145)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3939)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:431)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:264)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1053)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:173)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2449)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:949)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:427)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
>       ... 115 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'frticket0*.sitePhoto' in 'field list'
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)

Comment: Post your code and stacktrace of error

Comment: As TEXHIK mentions, a stacktrace (and maybe more code other than that single line - Is this the line where the error is thrown?) is needed so we can help you. This just says "I try to load an entity, and I get an exception". We have no way of knowing why.

Comment: yes.. that is the line throwing error